# a line in my code is giving me "subscript out of range error"

Tags: vba

I am getting the above error with this code... I am not sure what is wrong with it.  Can anyone help please?

Error on this line:

```
If Sheets(“TimeRecord”).Cells(i + 1, 1).Value >= Sheets("Resources").Range("C4").Value Then
```

Whole code:

```
Sub ProduceResourceReport()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
j = 8
For i = 1 To 1000
    If Sheets(“TimeRecord”).Cells(i + 1, 1).Value >= Sheets("Resources").Range("C4").Value Then
        Cells(j, 1).Value = Sheets("TimeRecord").Cells(i + 1, 15)
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the value of i?

Comment: It is in a for statement from 1 to 1000.

Comment: Put `Debug.Print i` just before that if statement to know what was the last value before error occurred. In the VBA Editor use Ctrl + G to launch the Immediate window to debug.

Comment: If it helps, here is the full code.  Thanks for any support you can give

Comment: Sub ProduceResourceReport()
'

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

    j = 8

    For i = 1 To 1000

            If Sheets(“TimeRecord”).Cells(i + 1, 1).Value >= Sheets("Resources").Range("C4").Value Then
            
                Cells(j, 1).Value = Sheets("TimeRecord").Cells(i + 1, 15)
                j = j + 1
                
        End If
    Next i


End Sub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means that one of the sheets is missing in the active workbook.

Make sure you have `Option Explicit` at the top of the module. Also delete the quotes around “TimeRecord” and re-enter them. They are wrong. I think VBA is treating “TimeRecord” as an undeclared variable instead of treating it as the name of a sheet.

> Option Explicit is mandatory for good coding.

```
Sub test()
    Dim i
    i = 1
    If Sheets("TimeRecord").Cells(i + 1, 1).Value >= Sheets("Resources").Range("C4").Value Then
        Debug.Print "no error"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It worked.  Thank you. You are a star.The problem was with ".  I copied part of the code from another macro and pasted it into a word document before copying it from the word document to the VBA editor.  In the process, the parenthesis got changed.